# Why my Angular 10 http.post subscribe block code is not executed?

Tags: angular, http, post

I am new in Angular and I am not sure what I am doing wrong when calling port http request when using Angular 10. My code is:

```
this.http.post<string>(url, tempUser)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {
          console.log('logged ' + res);
          this.onRegisteredLogin(tempUser);
          this.router.navigate(['']);
        }
        else {
          // registration failed
          this.form.setErrors({
            'register': 'User registration failed.'
          });
        }
```

Actually the POST request by itself worls fine. The code above creates new user via Web API. The problem is that these lines are not executed, because of some reason:

```
console.log('logged ' + res);
          this.onRegisteredLogin(tempUser);
          this.router.navigate(['']);
```

And I do not know why.

Comment: So what is the exact response you get back from your post?

Comment: Actualy nothing is logged in the console. And response should be status code.

Comment: in Angular httpClient receive a json object (by defect), a string, using `{responseType: 'text'}` or a full request (using `{ observe: 'response' }`. See https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response. But b e sure you received a response using F12 and check the Network (it's possible you received a 404 error)

Comment: Indeed, the console is irrelevant- what is the exact response you’re getting back? Check your network tab in the console. 
Is it - maybe - not a 200 response?

Comment: The server is likely not completing the request, making the request hang. I'd guess that it'd time out after a while, and throw and error.

Comment: I just checked, for my POST request I receive `200`. I belive it will not help with my issue :/ Maybe there is something wrong with my `res` parameter?